# How can I set y-intercept to zero in plotly with simple example of issue

Tags: r, plotly

I've had a great time getting to learn R, but I have struggled with one thing in my Plotly graph..

Below is a simple example of the issue I am having. Basically the plot is setting the y-intercept at my second data point "3.5%". I want the intercept to cross at y = 0 so that both of my values show up on the bar plot side by side

```
library(plotly)

x <- c("Unlevered", "Levered")
y <- c("4.5%","3.5%")
summary_plot <-  data.frame(x, y)
plot_ly(data = summary_plot, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = "bar")
```

Here is what my plot currently looks like:
[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0bnc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
s <- seq(0, 4.5)
p <- plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by `relevel`-ing your `factor` values in `y`:

```
library(plotly)
x <- c("Unlevered", "Levered")
y <- c("4.5%","3.5%")
summary_plot <-  data.frame(x, y)
levels(summary_plot$y) <- c(levels(summary_plot$y), '0.0%')
summary_plot$y <- factor(summary_plot$y, levels = sort(levels(summary_plot$y)))
plot_ly(data = summary_plot, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = "bar")
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmmm. I copied your code above into a new script in RStudio and my graph looks different. I get a sliver of the 3.5%, and then a large 4.5% bar. There is no 0.0% axis displayed on my graph. I'm a little confused on what is happening in this leveling.

Shouldn't plotly be smart and figure out that 0 should be the bottom of the graph? I guess I'm very surprised that a simple chart like this is causing me so many problems

Comment: I've realized that my issue is my data.frame already has the '%' symbols attached. I removed them from the code so that my data.frame is just numbers.

Does anyone know how to format the Y-axis for percent?!